# How to include interactive d3 visualizations in a shower presentation

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, presentation

I would like to present some [d3](http://d3js.org) svg visualizations inside a [shower](http://shwr.me/) html5 presentation.

However, the d3 mouse and click events are not firing when embedded in shower.

Eg. I have [downloaded shower](https://github.com/shower/shower) v1.0.8, and pasted the example code from the [Collapsible Force diagram](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1062288) into a `<section>` in `index.html`. At that link, you can drag nodes around; inside shower, this is not possible.

Any ideas? Thanks!

(I have also raised this as an [issue](https://github.com/shower/shower/issues/192) on the github page.)